# Android open source project cannot import a class

Tags: android, import, android-source

I am working on Android Open Source Project, my purpose is logging an API when an application call to that API.
So, I add

```
Log.d("Log API","params");
```

for example, in

```
libcore/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.java
```

**Code**

```
import android.util.Log;

class classname(){

public String method1(String param){      

      Log.d("Tag",param);
   }   
}
```

When I run make, errors appear

```
libcore/dalvik/src/main/java/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
import android.util.Log;
                   ^
  symbol:   class Log
  location: package android.util
```

Finally, my question is 
- Why I can not import Log Class?
- How do I import Log Class to use?

Answer (score 0):

Your class name wrong

```
import android.util.Log;

    class classname{

    public String method1(String param){      
          Log.d("Tag",param);
       }   
    }
```

Comment: I confirmed the package and class name is absolute exactly